# Javascript reference in loop: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, forms, this, document

I tried debugging my code for like a few hour but I got nothing out of it. The issue is that it makes absolutely no sense on why it reports an error every time I tried to use document.forms[0][i] *(i as the iterator)* in the event listener but **"this"** satisfies the code.

```
//broken
var addListeners = function() {
    var i;
    var formFields = document.forms[0];
    var formSubmit = formFields["submit"];

    for (i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
        if (formFields[i] != formSubmit) {
            formFields[i].onblur = (function () {
                checkNonEmpty(formFields[i]);
            });
        }
    }
};

//works
var addListeners = function() {
    var i;
    var formFields = document.forms[0];
    var formSubmit = formFields["submit"];

    for (i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
        if (formFields[i] != formSubmit) {
            formFields[i].onblur = (function () {
                checkNonEmpty(this);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Wouldn't **"this"** refer to document.forms[0][i]?... formFields references to document.forms[0]. However the exact same code *(with "this" where formFields[i] is at)* works just fine.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PbHwy/

Comment: Please post the exact error message. It also helps if you provide a little [demo](http://sscce.org). You can use http://http://jsfiddle.net/ for this.

Comment: When the onblur event occurs on the form field... Here is the error that pops up in the dev console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cranio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11061857/1139697) already contains the root of the matter. To get rid of this you can either include `formFields[i]` by using closures

```
var blurCallbackGenerator = function(element){
    return function () {
        checkNonEmpty(element);
    };
};
formFields[i].onblur = blurCallbackGenerator(formFields[i]);

/* // dense version:
formFields[i].onblur = (function(element){
    return function () {
        checkNonEmpty(element);
    };
})(formFields[i]);
*/
```

or simply using `this`.

See also:

- MDN: [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops:_A_common_mistake)

Comment: I read the link but I don't understand the logic of returning an anonymous function inside the event handler. This really confuses me. :( Does it create a new scope or something?

Comment: @W3Geek: You have to create a function for each `formFields[i]` which is independent from `i`, since `i` will change its value. I changed my code a little bit so that it's easier to see.

Comment: I think I figured it out but don't quote me on it. So every time "i" iterates a new function will be returned. In my broken code, "i" kept on iterating and it either confused or overwrite the previous onblur callback?

Comment: @W3Geek: JavaScript uses references - so all `i`s are the same in your current listeners. Your loop will exit if and only if `i === formFields.length`. After this a `onblur` event will try to execute `checkNonEmpty(formFields[i])`, which is now `checkNonEmpty(formFields[formFields.length])`, thus resulting in a `TypeError`. This is why you have to get `i` or the specific element bound to your function. This can be easily achieved with closures.

Comment: Perfect answer! :) When I was debugging the code I knew something was up with the i's. I need to study up more on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

Because you define `formFields` in a scope outside (or better, different than) the event listener. When the event listener is called, it is called not in the `addListeners` function where you define `formFields`, but "independently", so the reference is lost and its value is undefined (but `this` works because it is not dependent on that scope).

Comment: Specifically it works because "this" is in a new scope at this point.

Comment: Yeah, I bet I should rephrase :)

Comment: No, the above is wrong. The functions being created are closures, which capture their lexical environment including `formFields`. The problem is that they're all capturing the *same* variable `i`, whose value by the time the functions gets called is not what they're expecting it to be.

Comment: If I just use document.forms[0][0], document.forms[0][1], ect with no iterator it works just fine... But the point of this code is to add the onblur event to all form fields within the given document. I think it is something with the iterator but I can't find out what it is.

Comment: because document.forms[0][0] is completely different semantics

Comment: W3Geek, if you want to verify my comment above then you can do so by putting `alert(formFields)` and/or `alert(i)` in the handler function and arrange for some of the handlers to be invoked. I predict that neither will say `undefined` but the latter will report a value that's too large and that's the same across all the handlers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable `i` (referred to in each of your handlers) is *the exact same variable* in each of them, which by the time the loop has finished has value `formFields.length+1` and is therefore wrong for all of them. Try this instead [note: the below used to say something VERY WRONG before I edited it -- thanks to Zeta for pointing out my mistake]:

```
var addListeners = function() {
    var i;
    var formFields = document.forms[0];
    var formSubmit = formFields["submit"];

    for (i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
        if (formFields[i] != formSubmit) {
            formFields[i].onblur = (function(j) {
                return (function () {
                    checkNonEmpty(formFields[j]);
                })(i);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

and you'll find it works (unless there's another bug that I haven't noticed).

If you can afford to support only Javascript 1.7 and above, you can instead write your old code but make your `for` look like this: `for (let i=0; i<formFields.length; i++)`. But you quite possibly can't.

Comment: Scopes are function based, not block based. This will result in the very same error.

Comment: Now this answer I can get behind. Comment cleanup

Comment: Why is return used in this function literal? I don't understand the logic behind that.